# How I can calculate in R expected value and variance of X and how do I get the probability?

Tags: r, probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, variance

In a survey I collected the following data comparing people who prefer to buy coffee or tea:
75% coffee
25% tea
I am assuming that 75% of all people prefer coffee.

On any given day 8 people bought coffee for the first time.

X denote the number of customers in this sample of eight who will like the coffe.

How I can calculate in R expected value and variance of X and how do I get the probability of 3 or 4 or 5 or 7 of the eight customers who will like coffe?

Comment: Is this a question for a course? In this particular case you better use some instructions on how to use R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming independence of customers, your $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=8,p=.75).$ So $E(X) = np = 8(.75) = 6,
Var(X) = np(1-p),$ and
$$P(X = x) = {8\choose x}(.75)^x(.25)^{8-x},$$
for $x = 0,1,\dots,8.$

In R, where `dbinom` is this PDF, you can get
numerical values to five places as shown below. (Ignore row numbers in `[ ]`s.)

```
x = 0:8;  PDF = round(dbinom(x, 8, .75), 5)
cbind(x, PDF)
      x     PDF
 [1,] 0 0.00002
 [2,] 1 0.00037
 [3,] 2 0.00385
 [4,] 3 0.02307
 [5,] 4 0.08652
 [6,] 5 0.20764
 [7,] 6 0.31146
 [8,] 7 0.26697
 [9,] 8 0.10011

plot(x, PDF, type="h", lwd=3, main="PDF of BINOM(8, .75)")
 abline(h=0, col="green2"); abline(v=0, col="green2")
```

[image]

Mean and variance can be found from the probabilities as $\mu = \sum_{x=0}^8 xP(X=x)$
and $\sigma^2 = \sum_{x=0}^8 (x-\mu)^2P(X=x).$

```
x = 0:8;  PDF = dbinom(x, 8, .75)
mu = sum(x*PDF); mu
[1] 6     # E(X)
sum((x-mu)^2*PDF)
[1] 1.5   # Var(X)
```

Comment: but what I can use in my case without the pdf ?

Comment: The PDF is the displayed equation. You can use that (with a calculator) if you don't want to use R.

Comment: For example, $P(X=7) = 8(.75)^7(.25)=0.2669678$ because ${8\choose 7} = \frac{8!}{7!\cdot 1!} = 8.$

Comment: Sorry, I'm clear now Thanks

Comment: x = 0:8;  PDF = dbinom(x, 8, .75) So, is better found the prob first and then the E and Var right ?

Comment: Formulas $\mu = np, \sigma^2 = np(1-p)$ can be proved using the PDF formula and $\mu = \sum xP(X=x)$ and $\sigma^2 = \sum (x=\mu)^2P(X=x).$ But many elementary probability textbook show those proofs. // If you know $n, p,$ then it's certainly easier to use $\mu = np$ to get the mean than to deal with the individual probabilities.

Comment: Ok, great. Did you know that if my dataset was generated from a binomial random variable, can I provide estimates to the two parameters n(integer) and p? Of coarse, using the equations for the expected value and the variance for binomial. Maybe a data with 3000 random numbers.

Comment: In R, if I use code `x = rbinom(10000, 8, .75)` to simulate ten thousand data values in vector `x`, then I can use code `mean(x)` to find the mean of that huge sample, which will typically be very nearly $6.$ // `set.seed(2020); x = rbinom(10000,8,.75); mean(x)` gave me $6.0131.$ // Bedtime here.

Comment: No well, in this case is just 3000 random draws. Not is the coffe and tea case.

Comment: Then you might get an estimate something like $6\pm 0.02.$